# мне нужно расширить фоновый цвет ссылки

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно расширить фоновый цвет ссылки sign in

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1324px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.kwadrat {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #181818;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', sans-serif;
}

header {
  padding-top: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text-logo p {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.text-logo {
  height: 20px;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}

.nav-links ol {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-links ol .padding-left {
  padding-left: 125px;
}

p,
li {
  color: white;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #181818;
  padding-left: 70px;
  border: 0;
}

.button-links {
  display: flex;
}

.border a {
  border: solid white 1px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="black.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <div class="kwadrat"></div>
          <div class="text-logo">
            <p>YOUR LOGO</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-links">
          <div class="nav-links">
            <ol>
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>about</li>
              <li class="padding-left">courses</li>
              <li class="padding-left">blog</li>
              <li class="padding-left border"><a href="#">sign in</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
          <div class="button"><button>&#9776</button></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что в вашем понимании означает слово расширить? Опишите что Вы ожидаете получить от кода.

Answer (score 1):

> Мне нужно расширить фоновый цвет ссылки sign in

Можно добавить поля у ссылки (см.комменты в стилях)...

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1324px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.kwadrat {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #181818;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', sans-serif;
}

header {
  padding-top: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text-logo p {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.text-logo {
  height: 20px;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}

.nav-links ol {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-links ol .padding-left {
  padding-left: 125px;
}

p,
li {
  color: white;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #181818;
  padding-left: 70px;
  border: 0;
}

.button-links {
  display: flex;
}

.border a {
  border: solid white 1px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* добавить это */
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="black.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <div class="kwadrat"></div>
          <div class="text-logo">
            <p>YOUR LOGO</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-links">
          <div class="nav-links">
            <ol>
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>about</li>
              <li class="padding-left">courses</li>
              <li class="padding-left">blog</li>
              <li class="padding-left border"><a href="#">sign in</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
          <div class="button"><button>&#9776</button></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, Вы ожидали подобный эффект.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.padding-left-border a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li class="padding-left-border"><a href="#">sign in</a></li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Ширину уже сами регулируйте, как Вам нужно